# Have C return a string from main

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

I am calling a C program  (binary, compiled by Code:Blocks) on Windows from a Ruby script (Ruby 1.9.3) but I'm having difficulties returning the results of my C program to the script.
My C program produces 2 integers that I want to return to the script, as I can't return two integers I put them in one string and returned it but when I'm running my script everything is working fine except that the program returns nothing.

After reading my C program again I understood that I was trying to return a string when main is defined as int main(). My problem is that I know that it can't be anything else than int main() but I need to get those two integers.

So for now my approach is to wrap my results in one string (`sprintf(output, "%i %i", i1, i2)`) that I return (`return output`), I then store that string in a variable in my script and chop the string to get the integers, in Ruby this time (`string.split(/ /).collect!{|int| int.to_i}`)

How could I get what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks for your help

EDIT : The Ruby line that gets the output of my C program is

```
results = `#{my_program_path} #{some_argument}`
```

And my C program looks like

```
int main()
{
char output[20];
sprintf(output, "%i %i", int1, int2);
return output;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling a C *program* (e.g. a binary executable), or a C *function* ? On what operating system, which compiler and compilation flags, which version of Ruby? Show more code please, so edit your question to improve it! Show some Ruby calling code, and some C "called" code!

Comment: Did you try to get the stdout of the C program?

Comment: Don't forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -g`. Your C code is profoundly flawed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A C program cannot return anything other than an integer. No program or script on any OS that I have ever heard of can return anything other than a single integer status code.

How are you reading the return of your C program? Are you by chance reading the output? If so, you do not want to return it from main, you want to print it out to standard out. To do so, replace your `sprintf(output, "%i %i", i1, i2)` with `printf("%i %i", i1, i2)`